# How to show hidden content when hover in CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, show, hidden

As the title says I want to show a hidden span "box" when hovering an image, but I can't get it to work, so I was hoping you guys could figure out my mistake.

HTML

```
<span class="DDAA__bg">
<h1 class="DDAA__headline"><a href="#">DANSK DYREVÆRN ÅRHUS</a></h1>
</span>
<span class="DDAA__pic">
<img src="img/DDAA-Logo.png" width="980" height="200"  alt="Dansk Dyreværn Århus"/>
</span>
```

CSS

```
span.DDAA__bg{
  height: 200px;
  width: 980px;
  background-color: #666;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

span.DDAA__pic{
   display:block;
   visibility: visible;
}

span.DDAA__pic:hover{
   visibility: hidden;
   transition-delay: 2s;
}

span.DDAA__pic:hover + span.DDAA__bg{
   display:block;
}
```

You can see here how it works now, not as good :/

http://jsfiddle.net/ary3bt83/3/

Comment: Not related but you shouldn't put block elements like headings inside inline elements like spans.

Comment: You can't select elements higher in the DOM with CSS so your selection will never work unless you change the source order.

Comment: I'm still an amateur in coding, but good to know :)
How would you set it up?

Comment: Depends on your actual requirement but - http://jsfiddle.net/ary3bt83/6/

Comment: Actually pretty good, though the box supposed to be on top of the picture, i fixed it with some margin(only way i really know how to do it :D) but it looks like this which is okay http://jsfiddle.net/ary3bt83/8/

But then a new problem occurs, everytime you move the mouse, it's flickering, do you know how to stop that?

Answer (score 0):

```
element:hover > other_element {
 display: block;
}
```

this is equal to the jQuery code

```
 $(element).on('hover', function() { $(this).css("display", "block"); });
```

But doing hover on css sometimes is really buggy...

Comment: element_which_will_be_hovered:hover > element_affect {
//style
} ... pretty easy

Comment: could you maybe give me an example, maybe change the jsfiddle i linked to, sorry to take your time, but never tried this sort of code before, and pretty lost what to do, even though you made it so clear :D

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly!
though when you move the cursor around on the element to be shown, it's flickering, and also every time you click on it, it disappears, you maybe know how to fix that?

Comment: that's a bug of the browser I think, in Chrome it is ok. But this hover is really limited, you cannot trigger other events as well, that's why u use jQuery, if you want the jQuery code, I can write a described answer as well...

Comment: css is made for styling, animation with css is not prefered ( though css3 has some pretty good stuff). jQuery works well on all browsers and is has much much more power.

Comment: I'm very new to coding, as you probably can see, and haven't really gotten to the point to understand jQuery and how it works and implementing it into your document and so on, I actually don't know anything about it

Comment: jQuery is a basic thing you need for coding stuff. I suggest that you learn at least  the very basic ( I mean just the simplest handlers and functions, not object-style programming and patterns ). Because css is basically for setting a color and javascript for animation this color and whateve :) Hope you understand me. Though if this is a one-time question, it is possible with CSS, but as a good developer, I wouldn't do it this way.

Comment: Maybe a onetimer, maybe not. But if i had to make something like this http://hellonicolas.com

is that impossible to do with css?

Comment: No it is not possible with css, maybe with some workaround, but there will be bugs because of the browser, use jQuery for this.

Comment: You offered earlier to write the jQuery code for me, is that offer still open? :) Would be very helpful! Would take some time to first learn jQuery basics and do what i need it do to

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have jQuery installed ( look for jquery.js / jquery.min.js in source code or google for w3c jquery install )

After this you write following :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// everything here is done once the page is loaded

// define hover event handler for a specific element
$(".the_hovered_element").on('hover', function() {
   // show the element 
   $(".the_element_to_be_shown").css("display","block");
});
});
</script>
```

Don't forget that you must initially set display: none to the div that is first hidden and then shown. Also instead of .css("display","block") you can have simple animation like .fadeIn("slow");

Comment: Nice, but how does it work, does i put the code in my html, css or even make a new document it refers to?
PS - I'm not online for much longer today, would it be okay if I contacted you afterwards? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't always have time, so let's keep it here.

the <script></script> you can write it in the html code, preferable in the footer after everything is loaded, or if it is longer and more complicated, just in a sample .js file without the <script></script> tags and after that include in html as script src=""

Comment: okay, thanks for your help! saved me a couple of hours of research ;)