# How to show hidden content when hover in CSS not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide

What am I doing wrong? I come from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26319532/5132778
My code:

```css
#txtleft {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 7%;
}
#txtleft.content {
  display: none;
}
#txtmiddle {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}
#txtright {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 7%;
}
#txtright.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content1").on('hover', function() {
      $(".content").css("display", "block");
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="txtleft">
  LEFT SHOWN
  <div id="txtleft" class="content">
    LEFT hidden</div>
</div>
<div id="txtmiddle">
  <div id="txtmiddle" class="content1">
    MIDDLE CONTENT</div>
</div>
<div id="txtright">
  <div id="txtright" class="content">
    right hidden</div>
</div>
```

i expect it to work fine but my firefox doesn't do anything..... i just want some code to be centered in the page and when a middle div is hovered it should make content visible left and right to the middle div

Comment: working fine in chrome..any console errors in firefox?

Comment: ok thanks, it works as code snippet here now too... but on my page it says: ReferenceError: $ is not defined on line $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: try changing your `<script>` for jquery as follows: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: check my code here... http://jsfiddle.net/a6ae6L9q/ btw: thanks for trying to help me man! it doesnt work for me that waay, but no more errors

Comment: See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/a6ae6L9q/1/)

Comment: did it help @UdSSR ?

Comment: ok that also works, yes, but with that code i still do get ReferenceError: $ is not defined when i put it in .htm file and open that with my browser....

Comment: Usually that error is occured when jQuery is nit correctly loaded..try downloading jquery and use it..or try to use the script i mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: wow, yes now it worked with your <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​, but it adds a space now between browser-top and my header, how come that?

Comment: See my answer .. @UdSSR

Comment: thanks mate! worked!

Comment: great.. :) glad that it worked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine..

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/a6ae6L9q/1/)..

Please change your `<script>` for jquery as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌
```

To remove the extra white spacing, add this to your CSS

```
html,body{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}​
```

**UPDATE**

If you are trying to achieve, like for eg: show the div on hover and then hide it when not hovered, then you can do it with jquery `mouseover` and `mouseout` function.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/a6ae6L9q/2/) for that.

And, the modified script would be like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content1").mouseover(function() {
        // show the element 
        $(".content").css("display", "block");
    });
    $(".content1").mouseout(function(){
        // show the element 
        $(".content").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

Comment: i got it to work another way, but cant remember what was wrong in my code.... thanks again! im not sure if this is allowed but ill ask straight: how will i get to work that content disappears when moving mouse away from the div?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/a6ae6L9q/2/) what you are trying to achieve?